# Orchard calling _orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(contentItem, VersionOptions.Published) takes a long time

Tags: c#, orchardcms

After calling _orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(contentItem, VersionOptions.Published)
the site is just stuck and nothing else happens 
any ideas?

Comment: This is not a particularly helpful description. Are there any errors in the logs? Have you tried debugging? What is the "contentItem"? You need to provide more information...

Comment: I actually found the problem, at least in some sort of way, I've added a dependency to Orchard.Taxonomies and used it to create a list and use it in the module so the user can select some of the items.
Iv'e probably didn't implemented the code for the Taxonomies  module in my module the right way because after removing from my module it stopped getting stuck when I publish a content item of my module,in the code or in the admin area

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem, at least in some sort of way, I've added a dependency to Orchard.Taxonomies and used it to create a list and use it in the module so the user can select some of the items. Iv'e probably didn't implemented the code for the Taxonomies module in my module the right way because after removing from my module it stopped getting stuck when I publish a content item of my module,in the code or in the admin area